# How do I use custom properties with the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer

Lets say I have a form where a user can setup a custom object with a few drop downs, and then save that object.  I am using the entity framework to handle the DAL.  For example, they are setting up a profile and have to select a favorite color and I have a few colors in a drop down.  The drop down is populated from a colors table.  What If I want to add "Other" as an option and allow the user to type in a value.  When I save the object, I grab the color Id from the drop down and save that to my profile object, but if they choose other, I want to save the contents of the text box instead.  Is there a normal way of handling this?  I don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

This is what I plan on trying, I will set the color id property of my profile to be a 0,1 relationship so it is not required, then I will add a partial profile class with a getter/setter for color name, in the getter, if the color object is not null i will return the name of the color, if it is null, i will return my custom property value.

Comment: Where do you want to save the content of the text box?

Comment: I was thinking about a custom object to store the propery name, property value and the identifier which would be the profile id

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a custom property in your data object and not point it to EF that it has a relation to the database?

Comment: I think you understand what I am doing, basically if they select from the available colors, then the profile entity gets linked with the color id they chose, if they choose other, i would set the color id to  zero and pull the color name from my custom property table.

Comment: By custom property table you mean you have another table in the database for "Other" and ColorId is 0 and you want to pull that in/set?

Answer (score 0):

The design as you describe would be create referential integrity issues. You are trying to create a field that is foreign key to the colors table and if that is not possible, the foreign key should point to another table.

A better design would be to let the user choose a color from the drop down, and if the color is not available, you provide the user with way to add the new color to the colors table maybe  through some kind of a dialog. The color they add would then be selected in the dropdown.

Comment: I would not expect it to point to the other table, I would handle that with extension methods on my partial class.  I dont think adding to the colors would be too good for my scenario as I want the items they choose to add to be 1 time only, not available for selection the next time around.